# Alocação dinâmica dando problema em c++

Tags: c++, alocação

Tenho [este](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem) problema para resolver no Hacker Rank e o meu código para a solução deste problema ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int **arr, arrqtd, queries;

    cin >> arrqtd >> queries;

    arr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int)*arrqtd);  
    for (int i = 0; i < arrqtd;i++){
        int size;

        cin >> size;
        arr[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

        for(int j = 0; j < size;j++){
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            arr[i][j] = value;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queries;i++){
        int row,col;
        cin >> row >> col;
        cout << arr[row][col] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O problema é que num exemplo de entrada como este:

```
10 10
3 916135 272188 794963
3 178997 502468 671251
1 122266
3 223511 996043 990104
3 319694 335208 200789
2 867809 273793
1 925358
1 71140
1 862238
1 994309
6 0
5 0
5 0
7 0
5 0
6 0
3 2
3 1
0 0
9 0
```

O valor inicial da minha matriz muda a partir da sexta iteração, gostaria de saber oque fiz de errado mas até agora não encontrei nada (e também gostaria de saber pq esse valor inicial muda do "nada").

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na minha máquina, funcionou. Slackware Current, GCC 7.2.0 e Clang 5.0.0.

Comment: Considerando que até tem o `#include <vector>` no topo seria muito mais fácil utilizando `vectors`, a menos que seja uma restrição do problema. Ainda assim do que executei e vi no código pareceu me correto. A plataforma da-lhe algum erro na submissão ?

Comment: Se é C++, por que não usar `new int[]`?

Comment: @lemoce, ao executar na minha maquina aparece esse print que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: @Isac não uso o vector por dois motivos, sou novo em c++ e não entendo e por que queria entender o pq de não funcionar da forma que escrevi sendo que não vi nenhum erro na lógica. E sobre a submissão, quando não dá erro dá tempo limite excedido.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pois não entendo como o mesmo funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De facto tem um pequeno erro bem subtil no seu programa, e é na alocação de memoria do array bidimensional:

```
arr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int)*arrqtd);
```

Que deve ser

```
arr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*)*arrqtd);  
//------------------------------^
```

Está a fazer um array de ponteiros, logo é o `sizeof` de `int*` que interessa. Apenas fará diferença numa maquina onde o tamanho de `int` seja diferente de `int*`, e por isso pode não se deparar com o erro, dependendo de onde executa o código.

Com essa alteração o programa produz a saida desejada:

```
925358
867809
867809
71140
867809
925358
990104
996043
916135
994309
```

[Confirme no Ideone](https://ideone.com/CQjQgt)

Recomendações:

A menos de fins educativos/ludicos, será mais apropriado utilizar quer `<vector>` ou `new int[]` como o @JeffersonQuesado mencionou por 2 motivos:

1 - Porque se tornam bem mais simples e evitam erros tal como este que tinha.

2 - São mais idiomáticos no mundo do C++. O código que escreveu é basicamente código C utilizando `couts` e `cins`

Comment: Realmente, agora deu totalmente certo. A respeito do código estar escrito "totalmente" em C se dá pelo motivo de eu saber somente C e estar aprendendo agora C++, por isso não sei e nem utilizei o `<vector>` e nem o `new int []`